# Forwarding display in batch context

Tags: linux, x11, xvfb

I have Linux compute server A on which I would like to execute an application, say HV (I use this HV application to render a CAE model and capture the image). Eventhough I run this HV in batch mode, from putty terminal, it requires X windows. That is I need to run Xming and forward the display from server A, else it exits with error "No valid fonts - exiting". (In this case I am connecting to server A from my windows laptop using putty)

Instead of using Xming, the workaround I use is Xvfb. This works great in 90% of the cases. In the remaining 10% cases, few of the objects are not rendered in the captured image file.

Is there any alternate to Xvfb. There are few mention on net about Xdummy, but not much details. Or, it there any way to pass the relevant font, without forwarding the display?

My actual use case is, I have web application running on another Linux server, let us call it Server B. When I trigger the event from the client browser, the Server B connects to Linux Server A via ssh and executes the HV application. Even in this scenario, I tried ssh -X instead of just ssh for the connection between B and A. Still the application is exiting error "No valid fonts - exiting" if I don't use Xvfb.

Comment: Each Xserver supports `-fp` option which allows to configure fonts. You may install basic X fonts on the server B (the simplest solution) or use font server (a more complicated). Usually an X application needs just a few fonts: `fixed`, `cursor` and few others, look at /usr/share/fonts/bitmap/misc/

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar issue with xvfb not working consistent and contacted the vendor, their suggestion was to upgrade graphics drivers to the latest version. It did the trick. Xvfb created consistent  size images.

Thanks,
anony